# Which one of the SOLID principles had the largest effect on your code?

Tags: design, design-patterns, solid

Which if the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) introduced by "Uncle Bob" Martin had the largest effect on your day to day coding? Please give details!

Answer (score 5):

All of them, and none of them per se - I started with OO programming about ten years before Uncle Bob's first book came out. ;-)

My favorite principle is DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself. Also called 'normalization'!

Comment: When I saw a question, first thing what appears in my head was DRY , so I guess its my favorite also

Comment: DRY is a good 'un, but it isn't part of uncle Bobs principles.

Comment: @Mongus: SOLID is good, but not comprehensive.

Comment: @Steven, I would say the SOLID principles could probably be seen as aspects of the pathway to DRY within an object oriented framework. I don't disagree with you. DRY is my guiding rule. The question was about SOLID principles tho - I was just being picky :)

Comment: @Mongus: didn't I see you on the 'why are programmers pedantic' question? ;-) SRP is the closest thing to DRY in SOLID, i think

Comment: @Steven, probably! :)

Comment: @Steven...I am trying to not to sound pedantic here...but the itch is just too bad. SRP and DRY are like apples and pencils - completely different. Sure following SRP can help you to be DRY, but you have to do a lot more than that to be DRY, and you can still be DRY without following SRP. You don't even need to be OO to be DRY.

Comment: @Mongus: I am proud of you for resisting for 4 hours ;-)  You are correct of course

Comment: +1.  IMHO DRY is the surest sign that your system is well-engineered.  SOLID will help you make it DRY and keep it DRY long-term, but as long as it's DRY you're not doing too bad.

Answer (score 5):

**S** ingle **r**  esponsibility **p** rinciple.

Whether I'm working a small utility or a large scale service, I like my components to do one thing and to do that thing well. It makes my components easy to test and promotes code reuse.

The rest are important too.

Answer (score 1):

I will say ISP and a to a slightly lesser extent SRP. I must clarify that it was much later after I started following these principles that I heard about SOLID. The reason SOLID is so popularis because, like Design patterns, it is summarization of good programming practices that programmers follows through intuition or experience and not an exercise in coining jargons (which I have come to believe is the major side effect of programming)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the largest benefit I had is from preaching SRP to other developers on my team(s).

God objects and 10KLOC classes are a productivity killer even on a small team.